# Does Apple maintain a public list of known serious bugs?

Tags: bug, apple-news

Is there somewhere public that Apple (or a third party) maintains a list of known serious bugs with Apple's software?

For example it would have been nice to have known:

1. That the reason that iCloud Calendar is silently failing to send any invitations to events I create is that for many users (for some years apparently) invitations for events with locations simply don't send.
2. That Apple Pay does not integrate with App Store accounts so that users are logged out of their App Store accounts when they pay with Apple Pay and are thus unable to track or change their order in any way.

These seem like things users would benefit from knowing. Is there somewhere that such issues are listed?

---

Note that Apple Support is well aware of these issues, recommending, respectively, (1) that users should "either not use locations or not send invitations" and (2) "not to use Apple Pay with the App Store". But I had to contact support to get this information, only after much confusion and frustration with each bug.

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not have a list of publicly known issues/defects/etc. About the only option is to open a bug report with Apple through their [Bug Tracking Tool](https://bugreport.apple.com/). If the issue already exists in some manner, your opened issue will be closed and marked as duplicate, with the issue number for which yours is a duplicate.

Sadly and unfortunately, you will not be able to access the information of the "*original*" issue for which yours counts as a duplicate. Also, it has been said but has not been confirmed officially, that your reported issue will raise the internal priority of said "original."

Note that, this only helps if you know about the issue, to begin with, and report it. If you want to find out about any known/reported issues, the best option available at this time is to use [OpenRadar](http://openradar.appspot.com/). This site is publicly managed and populated voluntarily, by people who have opened issues with the bug reporting tool mentioned above, and added their information (issue tracking number, details, specifics, status, etc.) to the [OpenRadar](http://openradar.appspot.com/) database.

Comment: This type of question and issue comes up on StackOverflow[1] from time to time. For example, this question[2] is similar to yours from a development perspective.  

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com

[2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144873/can-i-browse-other-peoples-apple-bug-reports

Comment: Sad indeed. Mostly this just demonstrates how far Apple is from the desired feature: a list of bugs in their products that helps consumers be aware of any major discrepancies between what it does and what its meant to do. In fact, that's really something that out to be mandated by regulation (another topic).